# Does such a function exist (prescribed convexity and pole)

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

I'm a TA for a calculus course this year, and we've begun discussing concavity, convexity, and applications of second derivatives. A student asked me the following interesting question, to which I could not give an answer.

**Question:** Does there exist a function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = f(|x|)$, i.e., $f$ is an even function, such that $f(0) = -\infty$ and $f''(0) = \infty$?

Of course, I'm being sloppy in the formulation, but the meaning should be clear: We want a function $f$ such that $f \to -\infty$ as $x \to 0$ and $f'' \to \infty$ as $x \to 0$. In essence, we want a function with a pole at the origin whose convexity increases as we approach the pole.

Perhaps some non-examples are worth noting: the function $f(x) = \log_e|x|$ satisfies $f(0) = -\infty$, and $f''(0) = -\infty$. The function $f(x) = - x^{-2}$ satisfies $f(0) = -\infty$ and $f''(0) = - \infty$.

I'd even be interested in an example just defined in a neighborhood of the origin, if one exists.

Answer (score 3):

Consider differentiable $g$ only on $(0,\infty)$ and show that $\limsup_{x\to 0^+} g(x)=+\infty$ implies $\liminf_{x\to 0^+}g'(x)=-\infty$. Apply this to $g=f$ anf $g=-f'$.

---

> Indeed, assume $\liminf_{x\to 0^+}g'(x))M>-\infty$. Then there exists $h>0$ such that $g'(x)>M-1$ for all $x\in(0,h)$. Then by the Mean Value Theorem,for all $x\in(0,h)$, we have $\frac{g(h)-g(x)}{h-x}>M-1$, i.e., $g(x)<g(h)-(h-x)(M-1)<g(h)-h(M-1)$ and so $\limsup_{x\to0^+}g(x)\le g(h)-h(M-1)$.

Comment: Good answer. I was thinking of Taylor's theorem but this is cleaner.  To wrap it up, the answer to the OP's question is no.